# How is it possible to identify which user account used which USB device?

Tags: windows, security

Assuming we are on a Windows environment... It is known that through the use of the Windows Registry and event logs, we can identify which USB devices were used. Is it possible to find which user account used which device? I am seeing hints of utilizing NTUSER.dat but it is not clear how to go forward from there.

Comment: To my knowledge, this information is not recorded.

Comment: What kinda of USB device are we discussing?

Comment: I would be interested in all, but can we take USB storage devices (USB flash drives, smartphones...) as an example?